# MongoDB: How to determine is specific value does not exist

Tags: python, mongodb

I can only find examples to find if specific Keys do not exist.

I have specific documents in my MongoDB instance that have fields like this:

```
        "actions" : [
            {
                    "date" : "2015-03-09T15:28:03Z",
                    "reason" : "",
                    "begin_date" : "2015-03-09T15:28:03Z",
                    "end_date" : "2015-03-09T15:28:03Z",
                    "action_type" : "Block",
                    "performed_date" : "2015-03-09T15:28:03Z",
                    "active" : "on",
            },
            {
                    "date" : "2015-03-09T15:28:03Z",
                    "reason" : "",
                    "begin_date" : "2015-03-09T15:28:03Z",
                    "end_date" : "2015-03-09T15:28:03Z",
                    "action_type" : "Alert",
                    "performed_date" : "2015-03-09T15:28:03Z",
                    "active" : "on",
            },
            {
                    "date" : "2015-03-09T15:28:03Z",
                    "reason" : "None",
                    "begin_date" : "2015-03-09T15:28:03Z",
                    "end_date" : "2015-03-09T15:28:03Z",
                    "action_type" : "History",
                    "performed_date" : "2015-03-09T15:28:03Z",
                    "active" : "on",
            }
    ],
```

Now, I am trying to generate a query to return all records where the "action_type": "History" does not exist.

I know the $exists operator can tell me if the "action_type" key doesn't exist, but I can't find any examples to tell me where I can specify what value doesn't exist.

In my head I want to say it's something like this (but obviously this doesn't work):

```
db.collection.find({ "actions":{"$elemMatch":{"action_type": "History"}} : { '$exists': false} } )
```

Hopefully this is a lot easier than I am making it out to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
db.collection.find({"actions.action_type": {"$ne": "History"}})
```

Comment: Yes -- as I expected much easier than I thought. Works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: @gleb1783 I don't think this give results which you expected, and above query not showing any results.

Answer (score 1):

Are you essentially looking to check if a value is not something? i.e. the key will always exist but you want matches where the value is not "history".

If so, there's the Not Equals operator:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/

Comment: Yup, you got it. I accepted Pierre's answer as he beat ya to it :)

Comment: Curse you, Pierre! :D